# Ubuntu 20.04.1 on MSI Cubi N 8 (UEFI): Boot from USB not possible

Tags: system-installation, usb

I want to install Ubuntu on my new MSI Cubi N 8 with installed 240GB SSD.
Booting from a USB-Stick is not working.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the boot order in the BIOS has USB before the SSD? Alternatively, is there a key to press at boot time to choose the boot device? If you’re seeing errors, it’s usually helpful to include those.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I succeeded using another tool to write the image to the usb stick.